# Is there an explanation for why Maleficent can travel between worlds with her green-fire teleport?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

In the same way that there is an explanation for why the Organization XIII members can (the portals to darkness)

Comment: The same reason as many incomprehensible reasons: "because Disney".

Comment: Frank, you also forgot that she's a powerful witch who can turn into a giant freaking dragon.

But in all reality she is a woman who is full of darkness and hate, she commands a legion of hearless already, so why not have a grasp on using the dark magic to teleport.

Comment: The question is more about *which* dark magic is she using. I want some of that too. :|

Answer (score 1):

Maleficent actually uses the same means of travel as the other villains of the game - **[The Corridor of Darkness](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Corridors_of_Darkness#Corridor_of_Darkness)**

[Maleficient KH Wiki](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Maleficent)

> After the destruction of Enchanted Dominion, Maleficent and Pete used the corridors of darkness to travel to other worlds, eventually ending up at Hollow Bastion, the former home of Ansem the Wise and the last remnants of Radiant Garden after a brutal Heartless attack, which would be the perfect fortress to serve as a new base of operations. There, Maleficent would find everything she needed for her conquest of the worlds, including a report about the Heartless by Xehanort under Ansem's name and the very Keyhole that would lead one to Kingdom Hearts once all the princesses of heart were gathered

To explain the Green Fire, @Frank is more-or-less logical to his comment of "*Because it's Disney*". In the Disney films, Maleficient's dark magic contains the green light and Disney more than likey wished to keep her eeriness portrayed.